# Team Foundation Server 2018 git commit author not syncing with TFS users

Tags: git, windows-server, team-foundation-server

Me and a friend of mine are setting up a Team Foundation Server for a Small Project.

Currently everything is working as expected, except the Author for the commits is not connected with the TFS user that created and pushed the commit. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6JQC.png)

In contrast, the Author for the Push is detected correctly... [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brjYm.png)

According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-names?view=azure-devops) Microsoft documentation, the TFS should get the right Author based on the Author name and Author email set in git user.name/git user.email and the TFS profile wich is set to exactly the same strings.

This issue is obviously not a showstopper, but in my work environment this problem does not occur...

Any input is much appreciated!

- Team Foundation Server 2018 Update 3.2
- Windows Server 2019